# Why testpmd will receive lots of "irrelevant" packets?

Tags: dpdk

```
Configuring Port 0 (socket 0)
Port 0: **00:0C:29:4E:90:27**
Checking link statuses...
Done
testpmd> set fwd rxonly 
Set rxonly packet forwarding mode
testpmd> set verbose 1
Change verbose level from 0 to 1
testpmd> start



port 0/queue 0: received 1 packets
  src=00:19:07:FE:04:00 - dst=**C8:F7:50:80:18:B1** - type=0x0800 - length=132 - nb_segs=1 - hw ptype: L2_ETHER L3_IPV4_EXT_UNKNOWN L4_TCP  - sw ptype: L2_ETHER L3_IPV4 L4_TCP  - l2_len=14 - l3_len=20 - l4_len=20 - Receive queue=0x0
  ol_flags: PKT_RX_L4_CKSUM_GOOD PKT_RX_IP_CKSUM_GOOD PKT_RX_OUTER_L4_CKSUM_UNKNOWN 

port 0/queue 0: received 1 packets
  src=C8:F7:50:80:18:B1 - dst=**00:19:07:FE:04:00** - type=0x0800 - length=97 - nb_segs=1 - hw ptype: L2_ETHER L3_IPV4_EXT_UNKNOWN L4_TCP  - sw ptype: L2_ETHER L3_IPV4 L4_TCP  - l2_len=14 - l3_len=20 - l4_len=20 - Receive queue=0x0
  ol_flags: PKT_RX_L4_CKSUM_GOOD PKT_RX_IP_CKSUM_GOOD PKT_RX_OUTER_L4_CKSUM_UNKNOWN
```

The dst mac is not owned by Port 0(00:0C:29:4E:90:27) but still can receive it. Why?

Comment: can you sahre testpmd `cmdline` and cross check `promiscous mode` is enabled or not?

Answer (score 0):

I know the reason.

I must disable promiscuous on the port.

```
testpmd> set promisc 0 off
testpmd> show port info 0

********************* Infos for port 0  *********************
MAC address: 00:0C:29:4E:90:27
Device name: 0000:03:00.0
Driver name: net_vmxnet3
Connect to socket: 0
memory allocation on the socket: 0
Link status: up
Link speed: 10000 Mbps
Link duplex: full-duplex
MTU: 1500
**Promiscuous mode: disabled**
Allmulticast mode: disabled
Maximum number of MAC addresses: 1
Maximum number of MAC addresses of hash filtering: 0
VLAN offload: 
  strip off, filter off, extend off, qinq strip off
Supported RSS offload flow types:
  ipv4
  ipv4-tcp
  ipv6
  ipv6-tcp
Minimum size of RX buffer: 1646
Maximum configurable length of RX packet: 16384
Maximum configurable size of LRO aggregated packet: 0
Current number of RX queues: 2
Max possible RX queues: 16
Max possible number of RXDs per queue: 4096
Min possible number of RXDs per queue: 128
RXDs number alignment: 1
Current number of TX queues: 1
Max possible TX queues: 8
Max possible number of TXDs per queue: 4096
Min possible number of TXDs per queue: 512
TXDs number alignment: 1
Max segment number per packet: 255
Max segment number per MTU/TSO: 16
```

Comment: thank you for confirming my doubt as suggested in the comment.